# How can I map string array taken from mongoDB and show one specific title/body per post

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs, for-loop

I have a RESTful app built with React and Express Node, in it is a simple form with body and title inputs overlaid on a background image, when user clicks save, they are directed to another component with axios.get request displaying the their post.

My goal is to retrieve the data saved and display the image/posts in an array. *Right now I am just testing the post retrieval, I will work on the images later.* When testing the route in Postman, I am able to see all my posts using `http://localhost:5000/getall`, however when I use this path in my axios.get request I am seeing all the posts in a clutter, not separated: see example in image below. To access the arrays I us a `<Card /> I import the a Card component (``) in my SharewallComp.js file.

How can I map this string array taken from mongo dB and show just one title/body per post?

I tried the following:

1. Retrieve data by id: `let res = await axios.get(http://localhost:5000/getall${match.params.id});` but I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`.
2. I also tried the below with out match params and my result was just the numbers see error screenshot below:

   ```
     <Card.Title className="text-center mt-5">
        Title: {(title).map((t, index) => (
        <Card.Text key={index} className="text-light"> {(t, index)} </Card.Text>
        ))}
         Body: {(body).map((b, index) => (
        <Card.Text key={index} className="text-light"> {(b, index)} </Card.Text>
        ))}
   ```

Here is my attempt: Mapping is not my strongest skill. Any help I appreciate so much!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Cards from "./Cards";

const ShareWallComp = ({ match }) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState([]);
  const history = useHistory();

    const loadimg = async () => {
      try {
        let res = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:5000/geturls/${(match.params.name="grace")}`
        );
        setUrl(res.data.map((d) => d.url));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

  useEffect(() => {
  // login code
    loadimg();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="getcross">
      <Container className="mt-5 ml-auto mr-auto">
        <div className="mt-4">
          <Navi />
        </div>
        <h1 className="text-center">
          ShareVerse
          <span className="text-success"> Wall</span>
        </h1>
        <div>
          <div className="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <Card className="bg-dark shadow text-white">
              {url
                .filter((name) => name.includes("grace"))
                .map((urlData) => (
                  <Card.Img key={url.name} src={urlData} alt="Card image" />
                ))}
              <Card.ImgOverlay>
                <div className="text-center"><Cards /></div>
              </Card.ImgOverlay>
            </Card>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShareWallComp;
```

Here is the component where I have arrays for inputs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ComponentName = (props) => {   

  const [body, setBody] = useState([]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState([]);

  const loadData = async () => {
    try {
      //   let res = await axios.get(
      let res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getall`);

      setTitle(res.data.map((t) => t.title));
      setBody(res.data.map((b) => b.body));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData()
  }, []);

    return (
      <div className="compoentclass">
        <Container className="mt-5 ml-auto mr-auto">
          <div className="text-center">
            <Card.Title className="text-center mt-5">
            Title: {(title).map((t) => (
            <Card.Text className="text-light"> {(t)} </Card.Text>
            ))}
             Body: {(body).map((b) => (
            <Card.Text className="text-light"> {(b)} </Card.Text>
            ))}
            </Card.Title>
          </div>
         </Container>
      </div>
        );
    }      

export default ComponentName;
```

example of posts clutered
[image]

error when retrieving data with id
[image]

the below screenshot an example of what I want my code to do:
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeNgZ.jpg]

Comment: The error looking message about `key` is not error, it is warning, you can fix it by [providing a unique key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: How are you rendering `ShareWallComp`? Seems like you're not passing it the `match` prop. Are you rendering it as a React Router path?

Comment: @codemonkey it is a router path, i had data retrieved from a component that had the id that captured the post and passed it in a url. I copied that component that rendered the saved data from mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to get all the data rather then mapping it : see the below corrected code, I hope this helps some one out there! So instead of `setTitle(res.data.map((t) => t.title));` and `setBody(res.data.map((t) => t.Body));`, just get all the data: `setPosts(res.data);` Then call `{post.body}`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import axios from "axios";
import "./css/sharewall.css";

const ComponentName = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
  const [id, setId] = useState("");

  const loadData = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getall`);
      setPosts(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="compoentclass">
      <Container className="mt-5 ml-auto mr-auto">
        <div className="text-center">
          {posts.map((post, index) => (
            <div>
              <Card className="">
                <Card.Img alt="" src={post.url} />
                <Card.ImgOverlay className="overlay">
                  <Card.Title className="text-center mt-5">
                    <Card.Text className="cardStyle text-light">
                      {post.body}
                    </Card.Text>
                  </Card.Title>
                </Card.ImgOverlay>
              </Card>
              {posts.map((post, index) => (
              ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentName;
```